# How to reference other containers in legend description?

Tags: matplotlib, legend

I would like to reference another container in the label of an element. I attached some code below, instead of it saying "<BarContainer object of 5 artists>" I would prefer there to be a blue box representing "data".

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = np.arange(5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bar_1 = ax.bar(np.arange(len(data)), data, align="center", label="data")
ax.hlines(data.mean(), 0, len(data), ls="--", label=f"mean of {bar_1}")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

EDIT:
I want the result to look something like this:
[image]

Comment: You mean you want to do something like this? `from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerTuple;handler, label = ax.get_legend_handles_labels();plt.legend([(hl, bar_1), bar_1], [None,label[1]], handler_map={tuple: HandlerTuple(ndivide=None)})`

Comment: @r-beginners I do not understand what you mean, your code gives me an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_artists'`. 
@JohanC Yes, but I would prefer the blue box instead of the name. I added an example above.

Comment: @r-beginners thank you, I was missing `hl = ax.hlines`. As shown int the second image, I want the handler to be in the label and not change the handler of the mean. Maybe one cannot mix label and handler?

Comment: As far as I know, I've never seen a mix of handlers and labels. Well, that's just my limited experience, so hopefully there will be some excellent answers.

Comment: Will the position of the legend change? I can think of a (little bit dumb) workaround to get it visually like you want it to be. But as I said, it is pretty dumb solution, so don't stone me for it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a dumb approach:

```py
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = np.arange(5)
plt.close()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bar_1 = ax.bar(np.arange(len(data)), data, align="center", label="data")
ax.hlines(data.mean(), 0, len(data), ls="--", label=f"mean of {bar_1}")
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax1.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax1.set_ylim(0, 1)
ax1.axis('off')

blue_patch = mpatches.Patch(label='data')
blue_dline = mlines.Line2D([], [], marker='', linestyle='--', label='mean of               ')
nothing = mlines.Line2D([], [], marker='', linestyle='', label='')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.axis('off')
ax1.legend(handles=[blue_dline, blue_patch], loc=(0.02, 0.7))
ax2.legend(handles=[blue_patch, nothing], framealpha=0, loc=(0.465, 0.7), handletextpad=0.2)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Who cares if it is dumb as long as it works ;)

Comment: Danke Karina, this works for me. Good idea making a subplot with the legend. This does not have to be nice or performance code, I only need some nice plots ;)

Comment: Bitte :) I think it is also possible to make it a performance code by using annotations. But it takes more time since I am not used to it.